# How to remove all files starting with a certain string in particular path

Tags: centos

I used centos 6.5

in **/** path I have a lot of files that started with this name **tmp_**

I work with a user **franco** who has a limit permission ( and I can't add permission to this user )
and with FileZilla when I try to delete these files, I have a **permission denied** message.

so the solution is to delete these files with command in putty tool

because in putty, I can use command like this **sudo rm .....**

but I did not find the exact command.

I found this kind of command :

rm ./-tmp_

I want only to delete the files which are only in \ path and not in its subdirectories and which started with **tmp_**

I work with critical system so I want to be sure before execute any command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find target files use : 
This will just print files on console.
find / -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'tmp_*'

To remove files (not directories): 
find / -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'tmp_*' -exec rm -f {} \;

Please use -maxdepth attribute if you want to target files to specific depth.

Answer (score 0):

The command "sudo rm -rf /tmp_*" is worked if the /tmp_* directory not used for you.